# Bootstrap carousel-control not working properly in Angular-Seed project

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-seed

I have added Bootstrap in Angular-Seed project. The carousel-indicators are working fine but there is problem with the Prev/Next button.

On clicking Prev button, it switches to 3rd image & stays on it even if you click prev again. On clicking Next button, it switches to 2nd image & stays on it.

Tried replacing JQuery/Bootstrap with the CDN links but their versions is not the issue.

Here is the carousel I'm using:-

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1" alt="Slide 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/2" alt="Slide 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/3" alt="Slide 3" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: since there isn't any angular code in this sample (`ng-app`, `ng-controller`, etc.), it is unlikely that angular is at fault here.  Also, what you are describing doesn't seem odd;  It is normal that if you are on the first image and try to go to the previous, it would wrap to the last one... are you saying that when you are on the last image and click next, it goes to the second?

Comment: @Claies. Added the description.

Comment: I created a bootstrap fiddle and it seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21930/. There is probably something wrong with the bootstrap CSS/JS file or perhaps the jQuery file. Let us know how you included all these files in your project and we should be able to figure it out.